# Custom Spell Checker for GIS SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Is it possible to implement a custom spell-checker for GIS.SE?

There are many common terms such as shapefile, ArcGIS, QGIS etc. etc. that are recognized as errors when people write down their questions. When reviewing/editing questions, such terms have to be repeatedly edited (or ignored).

I don't know how the spell-checkers work, but it would be nice if it can recognize GIS terms.

Comment: No but you can add custom spellings to your web browser example firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker

Comment: This would need to be implemented at the SE level before anything GIS specific could be done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3932/215590

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe the spell checker results you are seeing are a part of Stack Exchange.

Instead they are likely to be your browser's in-built spell checker, which you can (usually) update and add these terms by using a right-click > Add to Dictionary when you select a word identified as incorrectly spelled.